# Need to programatically edit a file on remote machine

Tags: c#, windows, remote-access

I need to be able to do it without the directory containing the file being shared .

The credentials of my application are of a user who has write permissions on that file when logging in via RDP for instance, but how/where can I input these credentials when trying to do the same in code?

Answer (score 3):

You could try editing the file using the "hidden" `$` shares.  So if (for example) the file is located at `c:\somedir\myfile.txt` and the machine is called `mymachine` the path to the file should be:

```
\\mymachine\C$\somedir\myfile.txt
```

Replace `C$` with `D$` for the `D:` drive etc...

Note that these shares may be disabled and may require different permissions from those needed for a RDP session, howevers its worth a try.

Comment: the point is that i have the credentials to use the remote hidden share - its just that i cant figure out where/how to use them programatically

Comment: You should edit your question in that case. Currently your question states that the directory is NOT being shared, but with that comment you suggest it *is* being shared but you don't know how to apply your credentials through .NET. A different question.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's a share or some service that is executing on the remote machine that can serve you the data (e.g. FTP) then that file is simply not going to be externally accessible.

There are the hidden shares as mentioned, which is well worth you trying in a pinch, though that doesn't particular solve the exact problem of how to access a file "*without the directory containing the file being shared*".